# I've setup the tezos node for Ghostnet testnet but don't know how interact with node

Tags: node, tezos-client, python

[image]

I'm facing this issue while interacting with my node

Comment: The error message you are receiving has nothing to do with node / RPC at all (this is why you were asked for details). You have a Python error saying you've written the code incorrectly. I googled the error and the first link brought me to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944657/typeerror-method-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given

Comment: Buddy I'm using the pytezos method not using the method of my own constructed class.

Answer (score 0):

To make use of a node you have to call the given RPC for the task you want. Here is an OpenAPI spec of the latest protocol related RPC's: https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/master/docs/api/kathmandu-openapi.json

And non-protocol specific RPC's: https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/master/docs/api/rpc-openapi.json

I've also sent you this link previously, to the library pyTezos's quick start guide, which includes samples of connecting to a loclhost node: https://pytezos.org/quick_start.html

They also have interactive learning section here: https://pytezos.baking-bad.org/

FYI, just incase theres any confusion, running your own node is good if you are launching your own application. However if you are only starting to learn, you can save yourself some time by using one of the many publicly available nodes. These shouldn't be relied on for large scale applications, but you can absolutely runs tests / experiments on them. E.g. https://rpc.tzkt.io/ghostnet

Comment: Like in web3.py we create the instance of web3 with the rpc url in tezos we can do it?
like thid
w3 = Web3(Rpc url)

Comment: @ShahbazAli have you read my answer?

Comment: yes I read your answer and following this link "https://pytezos.org/quick_start.html"

Comment: my code is that

opg= pytezos.using(shell='https://rpc.ghostnet.teztnets.xyz')
    bal = opg.balance(address)
    print(bal)

Comment: and I'm not getting the address of any account

Comment: @ShahbazAli if your question has changed, please edit your question and add your code and any errors that you receive

Comment: still my question is same bro I have just change thie link of rpc but still it's showing errors

Comment: @ShahbazAli what "error" you've not shown any errors. Please edit your question, show your entire code, and take a screenshot of the error and post it. You are being asked to do this, beacuse your question is not clear

Comment: **CODE**
`def getBal(address):
    opg= pytezos.using(shell='http://localhost:8732')
    bal = opg.balance(address)
    print(bal)


getBal('tz1RsunQa8nMKTG1BbQNxZN4p4Usx9AZrZWZ')`


**Errors**

`raceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shahbaz/Desktop/Bitjeem_Tezos/sendXtz.py", line 57, in <module>
    getBal('tz1RsunQa8nMKTG1BbQNxZN4p4Usx9AZrZWZ')
  File "/home/shahbaz/Desktop/Bitjeem_Tezos/sendXtz.py", line 53, in getBal
    bal = opg.balance(address)
TypeError: PyTezosClient.balance() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Comment: @ShahbazAli please edit your question and use the code formatting tools so the code is readable. Don't post code in comments

Comment: question updated 
@Simon McLoughlin